# The use of "a" in English

Tags: grammar

My question is why :a: is used in the following structure.
A + ving  such as in “a bringing together, a coming together of …” 
Ving should be treated as an uncountable, or if an article is required “the” should be sued instead. Thus, “the bringing together, the coming together of …”
Thank you so much in advance for all the answers.

Comment: One about all the verbal nouns: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Verbal_noun And one about the deverbal noun, the one you are talking about: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deverbal_noun. BTW, it is a great question.

Answer (score 2):

Normally, "bringing" or "coming" might appear as *participles* - verb forms indicating that a person is in the act of performing one of the two actions. But "bringing" and "coming" can also take on another form - a *gerund*.

A *gerund* is the noun form of a verb, usually ending in -ing and identical to the present active participle. Since it's a noun, you can treat it as a single unit and can introduce it with "a."

Examples:
*It was a strange happening.*
*John wants to go to a running of the bulls.*
*A falling of debris followed the explosion.*